# How to put roman numerals in table of contents before Introduction?

Tags: table-of-contents, roman-numerals

[image]My counter is set from the Introduction and goes until the very end.

How can I set roman numerals before the Introduction in the toc?

My document class is: 
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}

and to set the counter from the Introduction I used:
\addchap{Introduction}\setcounter{page}{1}

Comment: Could you provide a smaal, compilable example that shows your current output, consisting of one page where you want roman numerals, then the toc, then one page where you want arabic numerals? Make sure that your example code can be copied, compiled, and then shows the output that you want to change (and nothing more). The solution depends on several factors, such as the documentclass that you use and possibly some packages that influence numbering. You can add code to your question using the small `edit` link below the question text.

Comment: You can put the command \pagenumbering{roman} right after \begin{document} . When you want to switch to arabic pagenumbers (in your case right before the \tableofcontents) you have to reset the counter with \setcounter{page}{0} and then put arabic pagenumbering on with
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}.

Comment: thank you, it worked @Nico.

Comment: So I convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can put the command `\pagenumbering{roman}` right after `\begin{document}`. When you want to switch to arabic pagenumbers (in your case right before the `\tableofcontents`) you have to put `\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}`. 
MWE to show the mechanism

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  %answer updated after egregs comment
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better `\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}`. It automatically resets the `page` counter and the meaning of `\thepage`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` or `\pagenumbering{roman}`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Roman pages}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Roman pages}
\lipsum[1-100]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter*{Arabic pages}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Arabic pages}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

To ensure un-numbered chapters I've used `\chapter*{}`, but then to get this to show up in the table of contents I've used `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Some Title}`